# Sound doesn't work after running VLC

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now, after I ran VLC for the first time, the audio doesn't work anymore. Before, everything worked just fine, but as soon as I opened a mkv-Video in VLC, the audio for the whole system stopped working.

After that I removed VLC and any plugins that have been installed with it, rebooted, but nothing changed.

Neither my monitor speakers nor my headset is working anymore, so I think it might be a problem with pulseaudio.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of my sound settings. Also to mention, my monitor speakers are hooked up to my nvidia graphics card via HDMI. (Newest graphics drivers are installed).

[image: Sound Settings (GUI is German)]

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I just noticed that YouTube videos also won't play anymore, neither video nor sound. It just freezes at the first frame, continues buffering but doesn't play.

I recently installed flashplayer, but removed it again because it was causing problems. So I'm using the native HTML5-Player of YouTube. I tried both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Open system settings, and click sound. Then can you post a screen shot of that on [imgur.com](http://imgur.com)

Comment: done :) (It's in German in case you wonder :D)

Comment: Click on the third one down, and try that. Like the word for volume ;)

Comment: Didn't change anything, still no sound on none of the four possibilities. Yeah, dang those long German words xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem by myself.

I once edited `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to disable the module-suspend-on-idle, because the first 0.5-1 second of each sound output was cut off. Guess I rather accept that than no sound.

As it turned out, I did this just before I launched VLC for the first time. Sorry for blaming you VLC ;)

YouTube now works again as well.