# First second of audio stream cut off

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Whenever I play any kind of audio from any source (VLC, kdenlive, YouTube, Facebook etc.), the first 1-2 seconds of the stream is cut off.

I already tried enabling `module-suspend-on-idle` in the pulseaudio config, but that led to the problem described in my previous question [Sound doesn't work after running VLC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503014/sound-doesnt-work-after-running-vlc).

Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but only with external speakers connected via the audio jack. As per @johnraff's 2020-09-15 09:32:52 comment at https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=6985, I modified `/etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.conf` to contain `options snd_hda_intel power_save=0` (i.e. changed the `1` to `0`), and rebooted.

The first second or two then did play, but on the internal laptop speaker; the remainder played on the external device.

The final fix was to open the Pulse Audio configuration utility and change the entry for the `sof-hda-dsp Speaker + Headphones` output to go to `Speaker` (in the `Port` field).

Answer (score 0):

I just installed pulse-audio/pavucontrol and everthing is working well now.